# Build Tensorflow with Bazel

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel

I would like build tensorflow with Bazel to use the compiled libary in c++. I run the following commands in cmd.

```
C:\Users\Furkan\Desktop\tensorflow-1.14.0>bazel build --config=opt
WARNING: Usage: bazel build <options> <targets>.
Invoke `bazel help build` for full description of usage and options.
Your request is correct, but requested an empty set of targets. Nothing will be built.
INFO: Build option --define has changed, discarding analysis cache.
INFO: Analyzed 0 targets (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 0 targets...
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.124s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: 0 processes.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

After that they create the folders in tensorflow, but the folders are empty.. What I do wrong??

bazel: 0.25.2
tensorflow: 1.14.0

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're typing an incomplete command, you should type:

```
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

The

> //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

is the location of the BUILD file, if you're not including it bazel does not know what to build. Including that in your command should solve the issue.

Comment: Are you in the source code root folder? You should be inside something like "C:\Users\Yourname\development\tensorflow-build\tensorflow" and from inside that folder you should run the command.

Comment: I cloned the repo from tensorflow and checkout r1.14.0.. Then I change to the folder tensorflow and use the command **python configure.py**. After this i us the command: **bazel build --config=v2**

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/BUILD this is the file that Bazel is not able to reach.

Comment: But this file are in my tensorflow folder. After I used the command from the top(**bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package**) i have following error: **Cannot find file at '..\\lib\bazel\bazel.exe' (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\bazel\bazel.exe). This usually indicates a missing or moved file.**

Comment: Silly question: have you installed bazel? Or maybe you should add bazel to the PATH variable. And also --config=v2 it's for version 2.x, giving that it's 1.14 you should change it to --config=v1

Comment: Do you have a Visual C++? Chocolatey installation does not include Visual C++, you should have it in your system. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Comment: That's a full guide more detailed that the one in the tensorflow documentation about installing tensorflow with Bazel, I suggest you to start over, I did it following it and hadn't any problem about it! Only thing is the version which is different, but with the 1.14 you might just skip the patching part (step 8).
https://medium.com/@amsokol.com/how-to-build-and-install-tensorflow-gpu-cpu-for-windows-from-source-code-using-bazel-d047d9342b44

Comment: Ok, so now i became a other Error: **ERROR: Skipping '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package': error loading package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package': Encountered error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': no such package '@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):** and **WARNING: Target pattern parsing failed.
ERROR: error loading package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package': Encountered error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': no such package '@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):**

Comment: Looks like you haven't ran `./configure` in the project root directory.